# I cannot display data from a JSON array into my table using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http-get

What i want to achieve is use the JSON details and populate the html table with 2 rows of 3 records.

My html file is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>DETAILS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="pr_app">
    <h2>DETAILS</h2>
    <div ng-controller="view_controller as view1">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <caption> PR DETAILS </caption>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Owner</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="items in view1.values">
               <td>{{ items }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

MY JS file that houses the module and controller are as follows.
NOTE: My first console.log() statement logs "(2) [Object, Object]" which means i am getting the response from my JSON file but the second console.log() gives me '6 undefined' so I cannot access the values of properties in my JSON array.

Can anyone point me is my JSON wrong or my http.get is doing something unexpected or anything else is wrong?

```
var app = angular.module("pr_app",[]);
app.controller("view_controller",['$http', function($http){
var self = this;
var record=[] , values=[];
$http.get('js/details.json').then(function(res){
    self.record = res.data;
    console.log(self.record);
    for(var i = 0; i< self.record.length; i++)
    {
        for(var key in self.record[i])
        {
            self.values = record[key];
            console.log(self.values);
        }
    }
}, function(){
    console.log("Something went wrong");
})
}]);
```

And my JSON is as below :

```
[
    {
        "product": "Adobe",
        "quantity": "1",
        "owner": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "product": "Adobe",
        "quantity": "1",
        "owner": "XYZ"
    }
]
```

Comment: Store reference to controller `this` and use that reference inside callbacks. See [John Papa Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#style-y032)

Comment: Also logic doesn't make sense in your `for()` loop where you overwrite same variable every iteration

Comment: @charlietfl the for loop is only used to access the property values inside the response. Can you point what or where am i going wrong and why i cannot populate my table? I took heed to your first comment. Since you marked this as a duplicate can you link me to more questions of this exact nature!

Comment: You need to start with understanding what `this` is inside the callback

Comment: @charlietfl I will but can you help or at least tell me how everything is right except getting 'undefined' for property values?

Comment: I suggest you study some angular tutorials for `ng-repeat`. To be honest none of what you are doing with the response data  makes sense but the json structure does make sense